# Decoding Assembly output in C Program

Tags: c, assembly

I write a program to swap 2 variables using XOR.

```
var1 = var1 ^ var2;
var2 = var2 ^ var1;
var1 = var1 ^ var2;
```

I Compile it to get the Assembly Output along with others

```
$ gcc Q1.c -save-temps -o Q1
```

I Get this Output in the Assembly form...

```
movl    24(%esp), %edx
movl    28(%esp), %eax
xorl    %edx, %eax
movl    %eax, 24(%esp)
movl    28(%esp), %edx
movl    24(%esp), %eax
xorl    %edx, %eax
movl    %eax, 28(%esp)
movl    24(%esp), %edx
movl    28(%esp), %eax
xorl    %edx, %eax
```

I am not Familiar with x86 assembly but i have worked on ARM assembly.
what does the numbers **24** and **28** mean here?

```
movl    28(%esp), %edx
movl    24(%esp), %eax
```

Comment: Offset 24/28 bytes from %esp (the stack pointer)

Comment: Those look like offsets from esp (the stack pointer). You typically used offsets from the stack pointer to access local variables and parameters. The stack grows downward, so you normally use negative offsets to access parameters and positive ones for local variables.

Comment: "I write a program to swap 2 variables using XOR." Why? Hopefully just to inspect the assembly.

Comment: Don't use xor swaps. Let your compiler perform that micro-optimisation automatically for you, if it deems necessary. By performing it manually, you're potentially exposing your program to undefined behaviour. Do note that this optimisation usually *isn't* beneficial. @DanielFischer Presumably this man enjoys playing pokies...

Comment: AT&T syntax sucks, especially the memory operands. It confuses nearly everyone who first sees it.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Do I want to google "pokies"?

Comment: This is a typical exampler for premature optimization:`gcc Q1.c -save-temps -o Q1` and caring for optimization is contradictory. And optimizing compiler should never need as many spills to memory as your assembler shows. Use `-O3 -march=native` and you'd see the difference.

Comment: I agree to @harold. Are you more familiar to intel's assembly syntax? if so,and you're using(or can update to) a recent gcc version,do the compiler generate intel's-like assembly syntax: `-masm=intel`. Also,note that you can make more slow using `xor` operation instead of a 3th variable in moderns machines.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes this was for inspecting the assembly only, i am a student and just curious about the compilation process.

Comment: I would suggest studying the compiler, in that case. You can download source code for gcc. Beware: It can take *a long time* to build. @DanielFischer Sorry. That's Aussie slang. Pokies are gaming machines with slots for money, lotsa flashy, bright lights and annoying music.

Comment: @Jack, THANKS for that masm option! That's REALLY an improvement, never knew it existed.

Comment: @undefined behaviour, studiying the compiler would be a bit overkill if oyu just want to learn a bit how the compiler output looks like. It really helps to become a better programmer, if you know a bit about it, but you don't need to go into that kind of detail, especially when you just started.

Comment: @Devolus Perhaps you could read the comments preceding, where the OP states quite clearly that he/she is "curious about the compilation process". It is, after all, the job of "a better programmer" to read carefully, right?

Comment: "studying the compilation process" could mean a lot. And studying the compiler itself is a long process. Writing some simple code and look what is generated is a good first approach IMO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`%esp` is the stack pointer. `24(%esp)` reads the value at address `%esp` + 24.

Comment: and a difference of 4 between those values because im using Integers.. right?

Comment: The difference of `4` is because your values are `4` bytes long and adjacent in the stack.

Comment: i tired this thing, i inserted another integer in between these two while declaring and initialized it too, but these two ended up adjacent. any optimization in work here?

Comment: There's always optimization at work, unless you go to some effort to turn it off.

Comment: @ArunKumar if the variable is not used it could have simply been optimized out. Anyway the ordering of variables in the stack is up to the implementation.

Comment: yeah.. i think the same @ouah

Answer (score 4):

I can easily see your confusion. Somebody correct me, but that is AT&T syntax, I think, and exactly how or where they put all the "%" signs and used parenthesis and so on, well, compiler writers can do as they please. (If you don't like what they did, write your own compiler; and do it for free and so on.)

I have re-written this in Intel syntax for you. I forget exactly what they call it, but anyway, in the their syntax the destination comes first in the instruction, and the other parts follow it. Brackets around a register name mean "The stuff which you will find located at the address to which this register points" With a lot of the registers, you can add your own offset, and the chip will generate the address with that offset added in.

Caveat, I think this is right, but I really should be home asleep by now.

Anyway, see if this helps

```
      ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;  Arun's Swap Via Xor Function                     ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;  Arun is studying C and ASM                       ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;  On Entry: var1 is at the 24th place in the stack ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;            var2 is at the 28th place in the stack ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;            Both of these are 32 bit numbers which ;
      ;            is why they are 4 bytes apart          ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;  On Exit:  var1 is in Eax                         ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;            var2 is in Edx                         ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


 Aruns_Swap_Via_Xor_Function:

      MovL    Edx, [Esp + 24]       ;var1 goes into Edx
      MovL    Eax, [Esp + 28]       ;var2 goes into Eax

      XorL    Eax, Edx              ;Xor them and put the result in Eax

      MovL    [Esp + 24], Eax       ;Store the result in var1 on the stack

      MovL    Edx, [Esp + 28]       ;Original var2 goes in Edx this time

      MovL    Eax, [Esp + 24]       ;The bit fiddled var1 is now in Eax
                                    ;Be aware, this is not exactly optimized
                                    ;  but it will work, and  this compiler apparently
                                    ;  doesn't want to take chances.
                                    ;  The brass tacks are that this instruction
                                    ;  as it appears here, is a defacto Nop

      XorL    Eax, Edx              ;Now Xor both of those values and put the result in Eax
      MovL    [Esp + 28], Eax       ;That modified value goes into var2 
                                    ;(Be alert, this is really the original var1)

      MovL     Edx, [Esp + 24]      ;The original var2 is now in Edx
      MovL     Eax, [Esp + 28]      ;The modified var2 is now in Eax

      XorL    Eax, Edx              ;Xor those two and put the result in Eax
                                    ;Now Eax and Edx hold each other's original contents
                                    ;
                                    ;(and life goes on)
```

So much for that. Just in case you are facing this in some assembly language course, this problem has fascinated people (including me) for years. Here's what your professors are probably looking for. By the way, you can find this on the internet, wikipedia, in fact.

The previous 11 instructions can be reduced to 3 instructions

```
      ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;  A slightly optimized swap function               ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;  Arun is studying C and ASM                       ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;  On Entry: var1 is in Eax                         ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;            var2 is in Ebx                         ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;            Both of these are 32 bit numbers, and  ;
      ;            so we will use 32 bit instructions.    ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;  On Exit:  var1 is in Ebx                         ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;            var2 is in Eax                         ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

 Slightly_Optimized_Swap_Routine:


      XorL  Eax, Ebx                ;Xor them and put the result in Ebx
                                    ;At this point Eax is var1 and Ebx is weird number

      XorL  Ebx, Eax                ;Xor that result with the origial var1
                                    ;At this point, Eax is var2 and Ebx is still weird number

      XorL  Eax, Ebx                ;Xor them and put the result in Ebx
                                    ;At this point, Eax is var2 and Ebx is Var1
                                    ;
                                    ;(and life goes on)
```

Finally, hardware designers and microprocessors to the rescue...

```
      ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;  A slightly better optimized swap function        ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;  Brought to you by Clint on Stack Overflow        ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;  On Entry: var1 is in Eax                         ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;            var2 is in Ebx                         ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;            Both of these are 32 bit numbers, and  ;
      ;            so we will use 32 bit instructions.    ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;  On Exit:  var1 is in Ebx                         ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;            var2 is in Eax                         ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;                                                   ;
      ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


 Slightly_Better_Swap_Routine:


      XchgL Eax, Ebx                ;Microprocessor magic, exchange them in one instruction.
                                    ;  Honest, hardware guys can do stuff like that. The previous
                                    ;  eleven instructions have been reduced to one. Ta-Da
                                    ;
                                    ;(and life goes on)
```

Comment: I think this statement unnecessary totally: "If you don't like what they did, write your own compiler; and do it for free and so on." IMHO.

Comment: `xchg reg, reg` is not a valid replacement for a conceptual `xchg mem, mem` since it sidesteps getting stuff from and to memory, and xchg with a memory operand incurs a lock on most platforms. Also, there is entirely too much commentary in these snippets. Finally, Reverse Nolish Potation is something else ;)

Comment: @Jack, if there is broad based agreement with you, I will remove it

Answer (score 3):

I recommend looking through Programming Ground Up ( x86 assembly , GAS syntax)

http://gnu.mirrors.pair.com/savannah/savannah//pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf

you can also try this

```
gcc -S -masm=intel test.c
```

to view intel syntax instead

Answer (score 2):

Those are offsets, you have to add to the value of esp to get the real address